# Android Programming ABC Tracing Application

Tags: colors, trace, picker

i want to make an application ABC Tracing , and i want to insert a color picker in my application , but how do 
i include the source code into my application ? 
please explain in detail , thank you very much

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  What is an "ABC Tracing" application?  (Is it a children's application to learn the alphabet or something?)  What do you mean by "include the source code into my application"?  Are you just asking how to build and run an Android application at all?  If so, you'll want to start with some introductory tutorials.  We don't really provide end-to-end tutorials here.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click in package explorer or goto file>import - choose svn
2. get svn repository location (for example this great library : http://color-picker-view.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/) from here
   `http://code.google.com/p/color-picker-view/source/checkout`
3. follow wizard importing the trunk/library, it should end up in your package explorer
4. Right click in your project to use the libray, select properties, select Android, at bottom select Add Library and select the color picker.